# Bad wifi with MacBook Air mid 2012

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, apple

I have a MacBook Air mid 2012 with i7 CPU. The one with Ivy Bridge.

I have connectivity problems with wifi running Arch Linux which I keep updated regularily. Throughput and response time performance decrease a lot when I move away from the AP (tried several networks with similar results).

Strangely I don't experience the same issues with OS X. I have tried switching between Mountain Lion and Arch Linux while staying in the exact same position. OS X performs perfectly while Linux can't even ping the router.

Are there any settings that I am missing? Should I use some particular driver?

lspci gives me

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 01)
```

Trying to change power with iwconfig gives me:

```
-> % sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
Error for wireless request "Set Power Management" (8B2C) :
SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.
```

***Addition:***
I installed the broadcom-wl driver. The connection seams to be a little bit more stable. But there is still a long way to go compared to OS X.

lspci now reports

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 01)
Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device 00e9
Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Comment: Just to clarify your device is wlan0? which driver are you currently using? have you attempted the others listed on the wiki?

Comment: I have not tested other drivers. lspci gives me "Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge" for the device. I would like to test other drivers, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Yes my device is wlan0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a similar mac that I run Arch on assuming you have a broadcom card there are three possible drivers that may (or may not) work. (broadcom-wl) works for me.  Also check pm-utils for powersaving settings. Further details on both can be found on the Arch wiki [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MacBook#Wifi)

For further help post the wireless card info found with lspci.

Comment: I set this answer as the correct because it led me to install broadcom-wl driver from AUR. The installation was simple enough and once rebooting the machine the broadcom-wl driver replaces the old one.

Comment: Further things to look into would be the other drivers and different wireless managers.  I use wicd-curses but  different people report that different managers have different effects on the signal strength and connectivity.

Comment: installed `broadcom-wl-dkms` and went from 2 Mbps to 69.